# Why is HandleExceptions disabling error displaying on local?

Tags: laravel

On one of my API-calls, I get an error `500`. No errors are logged in my *laravel.log* and the response is empty. This is of course really hard to debug.

Checking the `HandleExceptions` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap` I see that in the `bootstrap` method, Laravel is declaring only to show errors on testing:

```
if (! $app->environment('testing')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
}
```

This leaves me thinking I should use `testing` while developing locally.

> Why is this not also enabled on `local` env?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Display errors does not prevent logging in `laravel.log`. Check your .env file, turn on `APP_DEBUG`, verify the log settings, and verify your web server can write the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6 and `APP_DEBUG` is indeed turned on. Other errors are both logged and responded through the API.

This seems to happen when I use `broadcast()` / `dispatch()` togheter with `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`.